# Why is this Preflight PUT request to Google Storage returning 403?

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to set up a user upload system that goes directly to Google Storage rather than have content pass through our server. To do that, we have the front-end first contact the server for a signed url and then send the file upon receiving that url. That all seems to be working. After getting the URL back, the front end then sends a PUT request to Google Storage.

Due to CORS, the initial options payload is sent and gets a 200 response. However, the following (example) upload gets a 403 with the following message and I am baffled as to why:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://storage.googleapis.com/spaceofmotion/2019-06-23/finish-getup-agile.mp4?Expires=1561322797&GoogleAccessId=admin-275%40spaceofmotion.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Signature=BikemcQ%252BNe6L8mqLeSplKSz9L6baZhf9Mntc%252BR%2FQVGtAiY0XTlGTSb9wSaVuDd9zfoW%252BdrN4Za8O%252BTvbSm4cx%2FrH4Ub%2FFa2BnqNB74HlpNoFSLjXRe1bqatjCThsWTuR%252B5ADHHfQeen5eGyPPHFwNar5fSgCbd6Cf3kwIkvPSRgltHUymGtlDLHwhguopi83%2FY7t8jKocEc%252ByEx1eSW6PPlPY3qvDINbaV5NZ2aZ45LZiI7c5yckmoNCvy2kcz2qUvS1bPA%2FUJCD25mda%2FTW1DFGp3T5RWncUVHsxMTt4CzZp7%252BUJNnZ44U1pKd1dU7FGl3t%2FucExuMzGN%2F%2FM4NwMw%253D%253D'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

The bucket is configured as such:

```
[
{"maxAgeSeconds": 30, "method": ["GET", "PUT"], "origin": ["https://www.spaceofmotion.com"], "responseHeader": ["\*"]},
{"maxAgeSeconds": 30, "method": ["GET", "PUT"], "origin": ["http://localhost:3000"], "responseHeader": ["\*"]}
]
```

Here is the initial options [pre-]request:

[image: Initial Request]

And here is the second request:

[image: Second request, gets a 403]

What is wrong with this setup?

Comment: 403 typically means your credentials were wrong or missing. You didn't provide a [mcve].

Comment: A preflight request is the OPTIONS method, which you have not included in your list of acceptable HTTP methods. Try "method": ["GET", "PUT", "OPTIONS"],

Comment: Thanks for the response @BrandonYarbrough. That's not the issue though as the OPTIONS request is returned successfully. (I also tried adding it to the cors setup and it didn't change the result.)

Comment: same issue, got 403 cors error

Answer (score 1):

Try consulting and validating the points for troubleshooting CORS problems in the official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#troubleshooting).

From your screenshots is possible to see that your first request has a 200 status, so there’s no problem with that request, and you can actually verify all the points of the troubleshooting document, but for the case of the second request there are missing the required headers for the CORS implementation (“Access-Control-Request-Headers”, “Access-Control-Request-Method” headers are missing) mentioned at the point 4 of the troubleshooting document

Comment: Can you explain why those are missing? The response to the first request says that the Access-Control-Request-Headers should include Content-Type. The subsequent request does include Content-Type.

Comment: So mostly the funtionality to perform the request is missing to add those param, have you inlcude them in your request headers? And is the Options request being performed automatically by the XMLHttpRequest? Are you using any JS framework to perform the call? As mentioned at another comment a representative version of your requesting code would be helpful in order to perform a reproduction.

Answer (score 1):

I am using nodejs, and `"@google-cloud/storage": "^3.0.2"`

I try it out, but don't know why. For my case, just change the `version` from `v2`(default) to `v4` for client library.

```js
   const getSignedUrlResponse: GetSignedUrlResponse = await file.getSignedUrl({
        action: 'write',
        expires: Date.now() + 60 * 1000,
        version: 'v4' // v2 -> v4
   });
```

Then, the 403 cors error gone. Here is the docs about nodejs client library: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/3.0.2/File.html#getSignedUrl

Here is `version` description:

> The signing version to use, either 'v2' or 'v4. Defaults to 'v2'.

The client `PUT` request success:

[image]

The demo url: https://github.com/mrdulin/nodejs-gcp/tree/master/src/cloud-storage/signed-url-fullstack

Comment: Unfortunately, I was using python for this.

Comment: @user592419 You can check is there a `version` option for python client library, and try it.

Comment: Aye, I ofc did check and there wasn't. It's only using v2.